# Why is the CPU frequency always very high on my system?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, motherboard, uefi, cpu-usage

I have a Windows 7 Pro x64 system used as a home server.

Hardware: Core i5, 4670K (3.4 GHz) on an ASRock Z87E-ITX with the latest UEFI firmware.

I've discovered today that the CPU frequency is too high when the system is doing virtually nothing.

CPU-Z shows a CPU frequency of 3797 MHz. From time to time it drops to 3597 MHz. Multiplier always at 36-38.

Task Manager shows a cpu usage on Core 1 of 5-15%. Other cores are idle. All processes are at 0-1% cpu usage (almost all on 0%).

EIST and all C-States are enabled in the UEFI firmware.

When I change the power profile to **power saver** the multiplier drops immediately to 8 and the frequency to 799 MHz. But this mode is not an option, as when doing some CPU heavy work like packing using WinRar the frequency is at max 2100 MHz (and usually at 1200), so it's too slow. Additionally the LAN speed goes from about 95 MB /sec to 8 MB /sec (file copy).

If I go back to the **Balanced** power profile (with default settings) the CPU frequency goes within a second to 3797 MHz and stays there.

I have tried everything besides reinstalling Windows, and still have no idea what causes it.

I hope somebody has the answer why the CPU frequency is so high all the time.

more information:

I've just discovered in Resource Monitor that "System Interrupts" is at 10-15% CPU Usage all the time. On other PCs here "System Interrupts" CPU Usage is at 0%.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution! The culprit was the Intel Graphics driver! I've updated it to the latest version several weeks ago. Uninstalling the driver solved the problem right away (even without a reboot)! I've then installed the old gfx driver offered by Windows Update and the problem remains still solved. 799 MHz at idle with balanced profile!!

Answer (score 1):

After many hours researching the problem, i found the real solution: Downgrade the INTEL RAPID STORAGE TECNOLOGY DRIVER (RST) driver to previous version. I've download this: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22194/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-RAID-Driver. It works with 11.7.0.1013.

The problem is related with power management and sata ahci driver.

SAMSUNG NP700Z5C-S01ES · HDD SAMSUNG EVO 850 512MB · WINDOWS 10 PRO X64

Bye!!

Comment: How does this answer the question? Do you have a source that indicates this resolves the issue of high CPU frequency?